# How to configure Sonar to authenticate using SSL Client Certificates

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, sonarqube, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy that authenticates users using SSL Client Side certificates.  I am trying to make Sonar V4 use the credentials that are passed in by the certificate from the reverse proxy.  However, I haven't had much luck so far with Sonar.

However, I did get this working with Jenkins and Trac already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't find one out there.  So I just made my own over a few days.

https://github.com/trajano/reverse-proxy-auth-sonar-plugin

Personally wasn't too thrilled to have to resort to dealing with Ruby on Rails within a Java app and learning the current API on the fly, but it seemed to work since the authentication is managed by Ruby on Rails rather than Java.